# Error 'undefined function' when calling an imported function from a JavaScript module file in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, export

I am encountering an issue where I have defined a function in a JavaScript file and imported it into an HTML file using the 'type="module"' attribute. However, when I try to call the imported function from the HTML file, it throws an 'undefined function' error. I have verified that the function is indeed defined in the JavaScript file. How can I resolve this issue and successfully call the imported function in my HTML file?

I have this "pagLibro.html" where I generate a bookpage, in its body I actually only have the navbar and the shopping cart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
      <script type="module">
        import { cargaLibro } from './js/libroPropio.js';
        window.cargaLibro = cargaLibro;
      </script>     
      <script type="module" src="./js/libroPropio.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/perfil.js"></script>
```

and the rest of the body it's completed automatically from a javascript libroPropio.js, where I do a few things to do a bookpage depending on which book you click on in a main page. The problem is in the function cargaLibro(), I've tried everything to make it work but it still says Uncaught ReferenceError: cargaLibro is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (pagLibro.html?id=3:1:1)

```
function renderBook(book) {
    let libroHtml = "<br><br><br><br>";
    libroHtml = `
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0" id="${book.id}">
               <div class="col-md-6 border-end" id="imagen">
                  <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                     <div class="main_image">   <img src="${book.portada}" id="mainProductImage" width="350" alt="Portada del libro"> </div>
                     <div class="thumbnail_images">
                        <ul id="thumbnail">
                           <li><img onclick="cambiaImagen(this)" src="${book.portada}" width="70"></li>
                           <li><img onclick="cambiaImagen(this)" src="${book.contraportada}" width="70"></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6" id="datos">
                    <div class="p-3 right-side">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" id="titulo">
                            <h3>${book.titulo}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" id="autor">
                            <h5>${book.autor}</h5>
                        </div>             
                        <div class="mt-2 pr-3 content" id="texto">
                            <h6>${book.descripcion}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <h3>${book.precio}€</h3>
                        <div class="buttons d-flex flex-row mt-5 gap-3" id="boton">
// THE PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE, AND I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SOLVE IT, IN CARGALIBRO
                          <button onclick="cargaLibro(${book.id})" class="btn btn-dark" id="carga">Añadir al carrito</button>
                          <button onclick="mostrarFormulario()" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir comentario</button>
                          </div>                                                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  `;

libroHtml += `<h1 class="titulo">Comentarios:</h1>
<div id="formularioComentario" style="display: none;">
<h3>Añadir Comentario</h3>
<form id="comentarioForm">
  <div>
    <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
    <input type="text" id="usuario" value="${username}">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="valoracion">Valoración:</label>
    <select id="valoracion" required>
      <option value="1">1 Estrella</option>
      <option value="2">2 Estrellas</option>
      <option value="3">3 Estrellas</option>
      <option value="4">4 Estrellas</option>
      <option value="5">5 Estrellas</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
    <textarea id="descripcion" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar Comentario</button>
</form>
</div>
`;

  if (book.comentarios && book.comentarios.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < book.comentarios.length; i++) {
        const comentario = book.comentarios[i];
        libroHtml += `
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card border-0 shadow-sm">
                        <div class="card-header border-0 pb-0">
                            <h5 class="card-tittle">${renderValoracion(comentario.valoracion)}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body pt-2">
                            <small class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${comentario.usuario}</small>
                            <p class="card-text">${comentario.descripcion}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
      `;
    }
  } else {
    libroHtml += `
      <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card border-0 shadow-sm text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2>No hay comentarios para este libro</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  document.getElementById("countResults").innerHTML = libroHtml;
}
```

the function is this one:

```
export function cargaLibro(libroIdDiv){
  var libroId = libroIdDiv.id
  var libro = listProducts.find(function (book) {
    return book.id == libroId
  })
  var cantidad = 0

  if (carritoMap.size == 0) {
    cantidad = 1
    carritoMap.set(libro.id, cantidad)
    console.log("PRIMERO")
  } else {
    var igual = false
    for (let [id, cant] of carritoMap.entries()) {
      if (libro.id === id) {
        cantidad = cant + 1
        carritoMap.set(libro.id, cantidad)
        igual = true
        console.log("IGUALES")
      }
    }
    if (igual == false) {
      cantidad = 1
      console.log("DISTINTOS")
      carritoMap.set(libro.id, cantidad)
    }

  }
```

I'm using it as a module because I need to import DBManager.js to connect to a Firebase database and that's when the onclick buttons started not working. How can I fix this?

I've tried doing window.CargaLibro = cargaLibro, declaring the function as a export function, but none of this is working.